# Can I install non-signed hardware drivers on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use an unsigned driver in Windows 7 x64](https://superuser.com/questions/124112/use-an-unsigned-driver-in-windows-7-x64)

I want to install the [Trackpad++](http://trackpad.powerplan7.com/index.htm) driver and the developer states:

> Prerequisite step: install [Power Plan Assistant](http://www.powerplan7.com/home.htm) for Windows® 7. If
>   it's already installed, you may, of course, skip this step. Power Plan
>   Assistant is required, because during its setup it will ask you to
>   override the Microsoft®'s uber-strict digital signature enforcement
>   policy specific to x64 only.

Source: http://trackpad.powerplan7.com/installation_instructions.htm

I have no idea how the 'Power Plan Assistant' overrides the policy, but I don't wish to install that software, only the Trackpad++ driver.

Is there something I could do myself to change the driver policy?

Comment: You can but doing so will place your computer at risk. Using the linked software will also place your system at risk.  The statement this does decrease the amount of securit your system has is hogwash.  By allowing an unsigned driver to be installed, ANY unsigned driver can be install, some of the biggest security threats in recent years were becase of fake hardware drivers.