# How do I run unsigned driver permanently?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

I [compiled my own truecrypt for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379644/how-do-i-build-truecrypt-on-windows/13414137#comment18336873_13414137) and doing the suggested F8 to run unsigned drivers worked. I was able to install and run truecrypt successfully.

However when i restart the machine and let it boot normally I can no longer use truecrypt because of unsigned drivers even though I have it installed. What can I do to boot normally and use my build of truecrypt? Can i modify the registry, add an exception, can i sign my own driver without paying anything (but it probably only work on my machine which is 100% fine),

What can i do to run my own truecrypt build on a normal bootup?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use bcdedit.exe to set testsigning value to yes/true.

Comment: Nice idea but it didnt work.

Comment: Also you need to sign the driver from Visual Studio. Using a test certificate.

Comment: Look also [here](http://superuser.com/questions/124112/use-an-unsigned-driver-in-windows-7-x64?rq=1) for another option.